# Install Magento2 Comunity Edition 2.4 Fail

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

Internal Server Error muestra este error y los logs me aparecen esto.
[image]

necesito de su ayuda por favor

[image]

gracias

Answer (score 0):

Following below step and successfully install Magento in your local.

Step 1: Download Magento using command line.

```
composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition=2.4.3-p1 <Folder name which download magento2>
```

Step 2:

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://127.0.0.1/mage243" --db-user="root" --db-password="" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="mage243" --admin-firstname="Mage" --admin-lastname="developer" --admin-email="test@gmail.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin@123" --backend-frontname="admin" --language="en_US" --currency="USD" --timezone="America/Chicago" --use-rewrites="1"
```

OR

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://localhost/mage243" --db-user="root" --db-password="" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="mage243" --admin-firstname="dev" --admin-lastname="mage" --admin-email="test@gmail.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin123" --backend-frontname="admin" --language="en_US" --currency="USD" --timezone="America/Chicago" --use-rewrites="1" --search-engine="elasticsearch7" --elasticsearch-host="localhost" --elasticsearch-port="443" --elasticsearch-enable-auth=1 --elasticsearch-username="elastic" --elasticsearch-password=""
```

Make sure elasticsearch install in your localhost.

After run below command.

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/media/ pub/static/
```

Make sure check magento Version + PHP version then  apply above thing.

Comment: i triet but dont working :(, 
PHP 7.4.28 (cli) (built: Mar  8 2022 22:39:52) ( NTS ),
Magento 2.4.3 p-1

Comment: add this code in .htaccess file location pub/.htaccess

############################################
## Enable rewrites

    ##Options +FollowSymLinks   # comment this line
    Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch # Added this new line
    RewriteEngine on

############################################

Comment: After added above line run again all magento above command